# Exposing an API endpoint using SharePoint app/addin

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-addin

I need to expose an API endpoint in an app/addin which published in SharePoint. My customer not giving access to SharePoint API. I can't directly make a request to SharePoint API then. So I need to create an app/addin and expose an API endpoint to receive REST request from custom third party API.

That endpoint needs to accept a file and save it in given site in SharePoint. Is this approach possible to implement? If yes how? If not then are there any other solution?
TIA

Comment: is this can be done using a provider hosted app. When I try to create a provider hosted app I have two options to select. web forms or mvc. When I choose mvc how can I create an end point to get the request from my third party server? do you have any idea. or any article related to this kind of development?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to create an app/add-in to expose an API endpoint that can receive REST requests and save a file in a SharePoint site, without directly accessing the SharePoint API. Here's an approach you could take:

1. Create a web application that will host the API endpoint. This can
   be built using any web technology of your choice (e.g. ASP.NET,
   Node.js, Java, etc.). The endpoint should accept the file as a
   multipart/form-data POST request.
2. Within the API endpoint, you can use the Microsoft Graph API to
   authenticate the user and access the SharePoint site. The Microsoft
   Graph API provides a single endpoint to access data and intelligence
   in Microsoft 365, and can be used to interact with SharePoint
   resources like files, lists, and sites.
3. To authenticate the user, you can use the OAuth 2.0 authorization
   code grant flow. This involves redirecting the user to a Microsoft
   login page where they will enter their credentials and consent to
   the app accessing their SharePoint data. Once the user has
   authenticated, the app will receive an authorization code which can
   be exchanged for an access token to make API calls on behalf of the
   user.
4. Once you have an access token, you can use the Microsoft Graph API
   to upload the file to the SharePoint site. The endpoint for
   uploading a file is
   /drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-path}/{filename}:/content, where
   {drive-id} is the ID of the SharePoint drive you want to upload to,
   {folder-path} is the path to the folder where you want to upload the
   file, and {filename} is the name of the file you want to upload. You
   can use the access token to authenticate the API call.

Comment: thank you for this answer. But with this approach it's not an addin/app that can be published to SharePoint. It's a separately hosted WEB API. I need to add an app for specific site in SharePoint. As I went through the documentation, I found that there are two ways of addin creation. SharePoint hosted addins and Provider hosted addins. With the provider hosted addins can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi, yes. It should be provider hosted app or any web app (e.g. Azure Function, Azure WebApp).

Comment: could you please provide a visualized sketch of architecture that you're suggesting for this development? TIA